# Quorum Minimum Number of Nodes for Raft Consensus and Istanbul BFT

Tags: quorum, raft, ibft

A Quorum Raft cluster of 3 nodes can tolerate a single node failure, while a Quorum cluster of 5 can tolerate 2 node failures. What is the equivalent if one uses Istanbul BFT?

Comment: my I am going through the same issue, I am creating a docker-compose yml file for Istanbul deployment. but while I am trying to install Istanbul-tools and trying to run the make command in the end it shows an error. this the error shown on the console make: *** [istanbul] Error 1 can any one help me out please ??

Answer (score 1):

Minimum for Raft is 3 nodes and minimum for Istanbul is 5 validator nodes.

Comment: why 5 at Istanbul ?

Comment: Actual minimum is 3 nodes, but that provides no resiliency if any of the nodes is down the chain will pause until all validators are back. At 5, your chain may tolerate 1 failure.

Comment: but when I run Quorum using istanbul with less equal 4 nodes, the transactions get stuck and not mined, any idea why is that ? :)